Unable to call Snowflake UDTF with bind argument inside the FROM clause in a stored procedure
Background
I created a Snowflake UDTF (user-defined table function) GET_MEDICATION that accepts language_key as input argument to return the data in the language_key specified while calling it.
Query:
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(GET_MEDICATION('de'));

If we call this UDTF GET_MEDICATION with 'de' as input argument, then it returns the data with German strings. Similarly, if we call it with 'en', then it returns the data with English strings.
Problem statement
I have a sample Snowflake stored procedure described below that accepts one argument Language_key, and inside this stored procedure, I am trying to pass the input argument Language_key to the UDTF, but while doing so I have get an error

Error: invalid identifier 'LANGUAGE_KEY'

Can somebody guide me if I am missing something here?
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MEDICATION_MODEL_NLS_Test("Language_key" VARCHAR DEFAULT 'en')
RETURNS TABLE ()
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
DECLARE
    res RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    res := (select *
    from TABLE(GET_MEDICATION(:language_key)));
    RETURN TABLE(res);
END
$$;

I expect this stored procedure to internally call the UDTF with the language_key parameter (the same input parameter of the stored procedure needs to be passed to UDTF input parameter), so that the UDTF can return the data in the required language (German or English).

I’m guessing the issue is that the input parameter is in quotes, which is forcing the case. I would never recommend forcing case in Snowflake, just use identifiers without quotes and Snowflake will ignore the case
